# How to retrieve the previous term status

Tags: guidewire

I want to know the previous term status of the policy through code. Can someone please tell me how I can achieve it. My requirement is if I'm trying to initiate a renewal transaction I need to verify whether my previous term is not in cancelling status, then only I need to allow the user to proceed for creating the renewal. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can access the previous term periods by using the `BasedOn` property. Here is a common example for checking the previous term's status

```
policyPeriod.BasedOn.Status != TC_CANCELING
```

The `BasedOn` property always returns a reference to the original period that created the next term. You also need to be careful and ensure that a previous period exists as BasedOn can return null if called on the submission period.

**Edit**: As pointed out by Martin Aavik in the comments, the exact requirement and place for this check are unclear in the question. However, based on the implied context, it appears that the check needs to occur before the renewal is initiated and the renewal period gets created. The below code will work best in that scenario:

```
policy.LatestBoundPeriod.Status != TC_CANCELING
```

If your requirement is to restrict a renewal from being initiated in case the current policy is pending cancellation (Canceling status) purely from a UI standpoint in case of a manual renewal, you can also use an existing out-of-the-box property `PolicySummaryHelper.PendingCancellationExists`. This does a thorough check on all open jobs to check for pending cancellations. Expanding the property below to show how it derives this value:

```
policy.OpenJobs
    .hasMatch(\thejob -> thejob.LatestPeriod.Status == TC_CANCELING)
```

Comment: It's unclear whether BasedOn will be available when this check is being performed.  That only has meaning after a PolicyPeriod has been created, while this requirement is to block creation of the Renewal based on the existing period status.

Your safest bet for this use case is to use LatestBoundPeriod to get the status.  You'll also want to look for Cancelled status, probably?  Or maybe that's handled in the ootb code.

It's also unclear whether you're doing this in the automated renewal processing or for a manually started case.

Comment: Thanks, Martin. I updated my answer to include your point. Even though the exact context is missing in the question, your interpretation seems to be more accurate. I have listed another approach to check for pending cancellations in case that may have been the intent behind asking this question.

Comment: Thanks Martin and abhijay. Yes, I missed to mention the point that I'm trying to achieve this from UI at the time when I posted this question. I tried to achieve it by using below logic

property get IsPrevTermInCancelling_Ext() : boolean {
var isCancelingStatus = false
var priorTerm = this. FirstIssuedPeriodInTerm
if (priorTerm. Policy. OpenJobs.hasMatch(\elt -> elt typeis Cancellation and elt. Latest Period. Status == TC_CANCELING)) {
isCancelingStatus = true
}
return isCancelingStatus
}

Answer (score 0):

This requirement can be achieved by validating the Open Jobs exists in the Policy Term before starting the renewal (Automated or Manual).

Automated Renewal : Call the below function from the Policy Renewal Plugin (shouldStartRenewal) which gets called before starting the renewal.

Manual Renewal : Call the below function at visible script from PCF to not let the customer view the 'Renew Policy' option.

public static function hasCancellingTxn(policyPeriod : PolicyPeriod) : boolean {
return policyPeriod != null and (    policyPeriod.PolicyTerm.Jobs.whereTypeIs(Cancellation).hasMatch(\job -> not job.Complete and job.PolicyPeriod.Status == PolicyPeriodStatus.TC_CANCELING))
}

Comment: Thanks Satish, yes I tried the similar approach with little difference in logic as shown below.                          property get IsPrevTermInCancelling_Ext() : boolean {
var isCancelingStatus = false
var priorTerm = this. FirstIssuedPeriodInTerm
if (priorTerm. Policy. OpenJobs.hasMatch(\elt -> elt typeis Cancellation and elt. Latest Period. Status == TC_CANCELING)) {
isCancelingStatus = true
}
return isCancelingStatus
}